# Collada model hide meshes

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, collada, sketchup

I'm loading a model that was exported from SketchUp (dae format) into my code. I'm trying to figure out how to hide/show specific meshes. Imagine a room where I want to toggle the whole TV object, it includes the TV, cables and a furniture. Is it possible to hide specific meshes? Into sketchup I made layers to do it, however it's not exported to the xml. Any ideas?

```
dae.children[0]
```

Comment: dae.children returns anything?

Comment: @Almis yes it is returning around 200 childrens. However what makes me feel sad is that collada model doesn't export my layers.

Comment: does each one of those children have a name attribute?